# what is the best structure for a project in codeigniter and how to use it?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, data-structures, module, controller

I have some weeks since im using CI, but now I've found some problems about the structure of my project, I would like someone to give me some clues because I am kinda stuck, the problem is this:

I have my project MVC, so, I am dividing it into files (each per functionality) for example, there is a file with all the functions corresponding at login, and other with all related at post (it's an example), but now I am on a moment where I need to use login or posting into another part of the project, reading I found out i cannot call a controller from another, I can use the helper but still I will need to use a model, so I have to take that code and paste it into the controller where I'm calling the model and so on (and it's not good), I found out I can use modules, still I don't want to go over them until someone could give me an experience of this, i wouldnt like to change the project, is any way I could run all those controllers (i know i can use run:: I'm not sure if i can send parameters in it), any ideas please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fair warning, this type of question will get shot down by many SO moderators, but I'll give you some tips regardless:

1. **Controller actions are single-use.**  If you find yourself with duplicate code in multiple controllers (or, needing to call a controller function from another controller), that's a sure sign you should move that code to a model or library.
2. **Models are object-specific, not action-specific.**  I wouldn't have a model dedicated to logins, unless you have multiple types of logins (most apps/sites just have member logins, but you might have administrators, etc. that are stored in a different table from the rest).  Instead, have a `User_model` class, and make `function login($email, $password)` a method of that class.
3. **Controller-to-model interaction should be very concise.**  If you find yourself with 30 lines of code passing data back and forth between the same controller and model, you might be trying to do too much with that one controller action.
4. Keep your models *fat*, controllers *skinny*, and views *dumb*.

Comment: thanks... still doesnt give me an idea of structure...if i move my code to a library i cant call my model from it...i need more like a module...

Comment: Yes you can.  You have the global `get_instance()` helper to access any loaded model or library from anywhere in you code...

Comment: Better yet, if you have code in a library that depends on a model, it probably shouldn't be in the library, but in the model...